# Is my entire React component re-rendering unnecessarily when the state changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create an accordion component using React, but the animation is not working.

The basic idea is, I believe, pretty standard, I am giving each item body a `max-height` of `0` which is affected by adding a `show` class to an element. I am able to select and show the item I want, but the animation to slide in/out is not working.

With the Chrome dev tools open, when I click on one of the items I can see that the whole "accordion" element is flashing, which leads me to believe that the whole element is being re-rendered. But I am unsure why this would be the case.

Here is the relevant `Accordion` component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Accordion = ({ items }) => {
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(0);

  const AccordionItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    const isOpen = index === selectedItem;
    return (
      <div className="accordion-item">
        <div
          onClick={() => {
            setSelectedItem(index);
          }}
          className="accordion-header"
        >
          <div>{item.heading}</div>
        </div>
        <div className={`accordion-body ${isOpen ? "show" : ""}`}>
          <div className="accordion-content">{item.body}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="accordion">
      {items.map((item, i) => {
        return <AccordionItem key={i} item={item} index={i} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Accordion;
```

And here is a codepen illustrating the problem:

https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-heyrovsky-xgcbe

Answer (score 0):

of course, its going to re-render. When ever you call **setSelectedIem**, state changes and hence react re-renders on state change to exhibit that change.

Now if you place this

```
const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(0);
```

inside Accordion Item, it would just re-render accordion item, but would mess up your functionality.

Comment: I thought it would only re-render the element(s) that have changed in some way, not the entire component. No?

Comment: nope the state is what is being looked at here. it depends where your state is defined. What ever components it is in. that component would always re render on statechange, or how would react show that change.